find range of cells which sum equals a given value
I have in a g sheet a column of values ( A1:A). How to find the range of celle which sum equals a given value in cell B1 for exemple. for exemple, if I look for 114 (value in B1), I find that the sum of values from A4:A15 equals 114. How can I automate finding the right range without looking for it manually?
Thank you in advance for your help.
I did not find a formula to do this
